# Negative result on the stack in assembly

Tags: assembly, stack, negative-number, att

Assembly AT&T.

Hi,
I have a problem when I try to do a **subl**.

In particular I'm trying to do **x - y** where **x < y**.
But the correct result isn't put on the stack.

Here a piece of code:

```
....
call read             # Function to read a number (i.e. 5)
movl %eax, -8(%ebp)   # Copy the number read into the stack.
....
call read             # Function to read a number (i.e. 15)
movl %eax, -28(%ebp)  # Copy the number read into the stack.
....
movl -8(%ebp), %eax   # Copy the number 5 in EAX.
subl -28(%ebp), %eax  # EAX = 5 - 15
movl %eax, -32(%ebp)  # Put the result in -32(%ebp)
....
```

If I print -32(%ebp) I don't get **-10** (5-15), but I get a strange symbol.

So, the question is: how can I store a negative number on the stack without change its form?

Thank you so much.

AlfonZ

Comment: Are you using a print function that can handle 32 bit signed numbers?

Comment: What 'strange symbol' do you get?

Comment: What value does your debugger show you for EAX?

Comment: The code in your question is not sufficient to demonstrate the issue. You should include the _complete, minimal_ code necessary to reproduce the problem you're having. That includes any code used for printing, unless you're using `printf` from a well-known libc implementation, but then you should at least point out where that function comes from.

Comment: @knm241 I'm using a function that can handle int values. If i neg the negative number, the function prints the corret number, but positive.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan
In this case, with 5 - 15, that is -10, I obtain the symbol '&'.
If I try with 10 - 15, that is -5, I obtain the symbol '+'.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer See the answer above.

Comment: @Michael here the code of print function http://pastebin.com/AsUbaUSU
Thank you.

Comment: @AlfonZ The reason I asked you what is in EAX is because you did not actually tell us.  "Some strange symbol" is not nearly descriptive enough.  What is the actual hex value in EAX?

Comment: Here your bug: `jge divide      # If EAX >= 10` in the print function

Answer (score 2):

The bug is that your print function was not designed to support negative numbers.

You can store a negative number on the stack (or elsewhere) without changing its form.  But you need whatever uses that stored value to understand that it is a signed quantity.

Your print function treats any value less than 10 as if it were a single non negative digit (by adding '0' to it and printing that single character).  When you add '0' to a negative number and print that character, you get the "strange symbol" you observed.